# AngularJS - Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, steroids

I am loading a bunch of data from a json file, and have used both `$http.get` and also Restangular to grab it.

Whenever I pass this data into the `$scope` I keep getting this error multiple times:

```
Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html
```

This seems to fire multiple times for each item in the array, so unsure if the data itself is bad somehow?

The problem only happens if I pass it to `$scope`, and according to [Can we use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) out of "filter"s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520866/can-we-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-out-of-filters/20532984#20532984) its happening when you call `trustAsHtml` on something twice, which I am not. Infact I'm not even calling this once, so can only assume thats happening somewhere when I pass it to `$scope`

```
$http.get('/airlines.json')
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.airlines = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

I can't find much else about about this error thats helpful. The data is below:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Private flight",
    "alias":"\\N",
    "iata":"-",
    "icao":"N/A",
    "callsign":"",
    "country":"",
    "active":"Y"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"135 Airways",
    "alias":"\\N",
    "iata":"",
    "icao":"GNL",
    "callsign":"GENERAL",
    "country":"United States",
    "active":"N"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"1Time Airline",
    "alias":"\\N",
    "iata":"1T",
    "icao":"RNX",
    "callsign":"NEXTIME",
    "country":"South Africa",
    "active":"Y"
  }
]
```

**Question:** Why is this error coming up when I pass it to the scope, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: And where are you using $sce?

Comment: I'm not, unless its something funky happening in $scope based on using appgyver supersonic with angular?

Comment: Something has to be loading it and attaching it to that scope variable.

Comment: Yup, it definitely isn't in my controller though. Interestingly it only happens if I use a multidimensional json object, if I just do a single level of values it works fine.

Comment: It happened to me when one of my property values were actually an array instead of string. in your case it might be happening because of speacial characters like \\ and /

Answer (score -1):

the solution lies in the way you are handling this JSON object.

```
 $scope.airlines = data;
```

is not the correct way as your response is a array of JSON objects and not just one JSON object . [ ] enclosure in JSON is used as an array so

```
 $scope.airlines = data[0];
```

will handel the first JSON , this is just an crude not clean method, but you can add the array elements via a loop.

A JSON response without array [] can be handelled by angularJS by the first method just fine but with an array needs the second.

hope that helps.